# Intellij comment format

Tags: intellij-idea

Now, I am using the default configurations, and the "//" is displayed at the first column when I press the "command" + "/", see the second line in the picture.

How can I change configuration to display the "//" at the start of the code and following with a space? Just like the first line.

[image]

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is an option in: **Code Style > Java > Code Generation > Comment Code**

[image: intellij cfg]

With "**Line comment at first column**" you can switch between:

```
    //System.out.println("");
//  System.out.println("");
```

So, you don't have a 'space' after comment (in first line), but its close enough :)

### Idea 2017.2+

Recent versions of IntelliJ IDEA support adding a space after the line comment. The setting is at the same location.

[image]

Comment: It would be perfect with a space between the `//` and the code...

It is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841706/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-line-comment-shortcut-add-a-space-after-in-webst/31842617#31842617

Comment: is there any similar configuration for HTML ??

Comment: THANK YOU. BTW, we even have that extra space now.

Comment: Reading your answer helped me see that IntelliJ has even further enhanced this option in more recent versions.

Comment: I noticed there is no similar configuration for kotlin. :((

Comment: Update: In fact there is a option for this in Kotlin but currently it doesn't work in IntelliJ Idea 2017.3.
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Wrapping and Braces -> Keep when reformating -> Comment at first column
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5590

Comment: File > Settings > Code Style > Java > Code Generation > Comment Code

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ 2017.2 now does exactly what you want.  I'm not sure when this was originally introduced.

Project Settings > Code Style > Java
Change tab to Code Generation, locate Comment Code section
Uncheck "Line Comment at First Column"
Check "Add a space at comment start"

Now when you press Control-/

```
    boolean goodCode = true;
```

becomes

```
    // boolean goodCode = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix comments during reformatting, go to file->settings->editor->code style->java->wrapping and braces->keep when reformatting->uncheck "comment at first column"

[image]