# Is there any way to have the line comment shortcut add a space after // in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

When using the shortcut for commenting a line of code (`command /` on a Mac), the code line gets a `//` added in front of it. (Pointing out the obvious for topic clarification).

Stylistically I would like to add a space between the `//` and the start of some code that I'm commenting out. i.e. make the comment leader when added  `// function foo() {` rather than `//function foo() {` which is the default.

What I can't find is how to change this setting in JetBrains WebStorm (I've already tried trolling their website and the preferences etc with no success) - I've also run many searches (my google-foo is terrible!) but have yet to find how to change this setting.

Anybody know how (or if?) this setting can be changed?

Comment: The relevant feature was added in a recent release of WebStorm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it's not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141701 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

UPDATE (20th April, 2016)

It's now implemented and available as of 2016.1 version.

`Settings/Preferences | Code Style` -- It was implemented for these languages (not sure about any other):

- Java -- `Java | Code Generation | Comment Code`
- JavaScript/TypeScript -- `JavaScript | Other | Comment Code`
- PHP -- `PHP | Other | Comment Code`

Comment: will do - thanks for pointing that out! Now adding 'prepend' to my list of words to keep an eye on as well.

Comment: At present, it is not yet implemented for Scala and many other languages. Ticket filed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167689

Comment: This is great for generated comments, but really stinks that it's not enforced by the formatter. If you'd like the formatter to actually enforce this, you can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5823

Answer (score 0):

I highlight the code that I want to comment out and use tab to indent, and then  cmd + /  to add "//"

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me. At least indenting with spaces :(