# Indentation of line comments’ slashes

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use IntelliJ’s function “Comment with Line Comment” it places two slashes at the very beginning of the selected lines. The forward slashes are not indented with the rest of the code. How can I make IntelliJ obey the line indentation when placing the forward slashes?

Example code:

```
if (something) {
    bar();
}
```

Using IntelliJ’s commenting function on line 2 results in:

```
if (something) {
//  bar();
}
```

What I want:

```
if (something) {
    // bar();
}
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Go to `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Code Generation` and uncheck the option "Line comment at first column".

Update Oct 2016 from @henrebotha in the comments:

> As of now, there's an additional option just beneath it that says "Add a space at comment start", so this is now supported.

Comment: This results in “//bar();” instead of “// bar();”.

Comment: I'm not sure if having that space is supported or not. @ChristianSiegert

Comment: It might not be possible, apparently JetBrain's WebStorm does not support it either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841706/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-line-comment-shortcut-add-a-space-after-in-webst/31842617#31842617 @ChristianSiegert

Comment: As of now, there's an additional option just beneath it that says "Add a space at comment start", so this is now supported.

Comment: how to achieve exactly the same for kotlin?(which doesn't have "Code Generation" tab)

Comment: For some reason, this option has no effect on my code - it's just not working...:)

Comment: This works when add new comment, not when format existing comment.

Comment: Same problem here, this works only for new comments and not existing ones.

Answer (score 14):

You can setup in **Code Generation**:
[image: Options]

Comment: If you use kotlin, please remember to modify the setting of Kotlin, not Java.

Comment: this works with Android Studio Chipmunk

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions the setting is called:
 `Comment at first column`

Just search for it in the settings window, then go to `Editor -> Code Style -> Your language`.

Comment: Sadly, for Rust this option is missing. :/

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking on how to do this for Scala, the `Line comment at first column` configuration is in `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Scala > Other` tab instead of `Code Generation` as with the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are feeling my pain, in a shared code style environment this might not work for you if `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Enable EditorConfig support` is checked.

It may well be overridden in your shared style.  You are going to have to talk to your project fashion police about that.