# Android Studio: Wrong line comment indentation

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When hitting `Ctrl+/` Android Development Studio would put line comment double slashes at the beginning of the line.

Is there any way to make ADS put line comment preserving correct indentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indentation of line comments’ slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342682/indentation-of-line-comments-slashes)

Answer (score 13):

You have to go to Settings → Editor → Code Style → JAVA. Select "Code Generation" tab.

Deselect "Line comment at first column" option, on Comment Code section.

[image]

This answer is based on Android Studio 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use kotlin, please remember to modify the setting of Kotlin, not Java.