# Disable indentation of commented-out code

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Under `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation -> Commented code` one can select `Line comment at first column` so that the `//` will be put at the start of the line when using `Ctrl+/` to comment a line. This seems like a good idea because it makes it easier to distinguish between actual comments and commented-out code.

However, applying reformatting on the code will indent the line starting with `//` to the current indentation level. How to tell the formatter it should keep it at the beginning of the line?

Comment: How to *disable* that `//` is placed at the beginning of the line is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32342682/905686).

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't find the setting in the settings editor, in the generated `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` there showed up a line `<option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />` (under `<codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">`). Setting its value to `true` solves the problem by keeping all comments that start at the beginning of the line where they are.