# In IDEA, how to add a space between code & comment automatically?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, code-formatting

---

### Example

**Example A:**

```
T result = (T) node.value; // keep return value,
```

There is a space between `;` and `//`

**Example B:**

```
if (k < 0 || k > size) // out of range,
    return false;
```

There is a space between `)` and `//`.

**Example C:**

```
if (size == 0 || k == size) { // append at end,
    append(value);
    return true;
}
```

There is a space between `{` and `//`.

---

I searched on Google, and found this post: [Is there any way to have the line comment shortcut add a space after // in WebStorm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841706)

The link only tells how to add a space after `//`, and that's the default behavior.

I didn't found any solution.

---

### Question

- How to let IDEA add spaces from the above examples automatically on formatting?

*(BTW, I am not saying that it's better, I just personally prefer to that, and trying to get it done.)*

---

### @Update - issue request created on Jetbrains

A new issue is created on Jetbrains's youtrack for this feature: [Provide option to add a space between code and "//" on formatting.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207008)

Please **up vote** it if you also desire for this feature.

Comment: Example B) you could write as "if isOutOfRange(k) return false;" instead. Never write comments that could be easily expressed in code :-)

Comment: @GhostCat Usually I would write it that way, but there are also cases that IDE will automatically format it to next line probably due to line too long. This is just an example. I am focusing on the `space` part for this question.

Comment: I don't see a way to set that up in IntelliJ. The space bar seems to be needed in this.

Comment: @Zephyr Seems so, I also check IDEA's settings, there is no such options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to add the space between the code and the start of the comment in IntelliJ IDEA.

Feature request to track the progress:

- [IDEA-207008](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207008) Provide option to add a space between code and "//" on formatting.

Comment: The link is the same as I mentioned in the question, that's not what I am looking for. I think this is a reasonable feature for IDEA to add in the future.

Comment: @EricWang I understand that it's not the answer you've expected, but there is really no such option right now and I've added the link to the existing feature request you can vote for to make it appear sooner. If such option exists in Eclipse, you can try using [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA as a workaround.

Comment: I just rechecked Eclipse, seems it don't have this feature either, though I do remember using that before, LOL. But still I think this is a good feature to add. The `IDEA-58488` link from your answer is an old issue request that want space after `//`, not between code and `//`. So, they are different, if I am understanding it correctly, then a new issue request is need I guess, and the logic could be: provide an option to add space between code and `//`, when  `//` is not at beginning of line.

Comment: I have just created a new issue on Jetbrain youtrack for this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207008

Comment: @EricWang Thanks for submitting the request, I've updated the answer.